# Working with branches in bitbucket and sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am pretty new to using advanced features in Git, and am wondering if   someone can help me understand branches a little better. I have created two branches in Bitbucket named live and dev. What I am trying to do is push changes to dev, and only update the live branch when I push to it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Simply you can achieve this by keeping pushing to dev and then when you want to update the live branch from dev you open a pull request against it from dev and merge it, check out https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request

Comment: You might want to look at Atlassian's [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) tutorial, where your *dev* would be the workflow's *feature* branch, and your *live* would be the workflow's *master* branch.

Comment: @EhabQadah thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm going to make a test repo and give it a try

Comment: @GinoMempin thanks for providing the article. I'm going to look over it and follow it. On glance over, it seems like it'll be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think git like a tree. A branch represents independent line of development.

So, branches actually encapsulates your changes. For example, when you want to add a new feature to the code, you create a new branch and push commit to the new branch.

Working with branches makes master branch is clean and unreviewed code (questionable code maybe?). It also makes harder to merge unwanted code to the master branch.

Comment: *It also makes harder to merge unwanted code to the master branch.* -- this statement is not accurate. Merging in Git is easy. What could keep your code outside the `master` branch is a policy enforced by Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket or whatever software runs on the server that hosts the Git central repository and is properly configured for team work. These are not part of Git itself, they are extra packages that wrap Git and provide a nice UI for administration, constraints, pull requests and code review.